# How can I check if .tar (not tar.gz) file is corrupt or not, in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compression, tar

When I was untar (ing) a `.tar` file, I get the error:

```
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: rmtlseek not stopped at a record boundary
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

[image]

Two questions:

1. It is possibly that file may be corrupt but how do I check if the `.tar` is corrupt or not?
2. When it shows me the file `ebd_sampling_relFeb-2021.txt.gz` and then continues to untar, does it mean `ebd_sampling_relFeb-2021.txt.gz` is extracted perfectlly fine but something else in the `.tar` went wrong?

I tried to google the question (https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=check+if+tar+is+corrupt%3F) but majority of them talk about `tar.gz` and not `.tar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When asking a question regarding Linux, try to state the distro you are encountering the error on. It might help others better understand the problem and in turn, to help you better.

OK, now into the answer.

You can use **7zip** to easily test whether an archive is corrupted or not. If 7zip, which is distributed via the `p7zip` package isn't already installed, install it with one of the following commands matching your Linux distribution.

**Ubuntu**: `sudo apt install p7zip`

**Fedora/Cent OS/RHEL**: `sudo yum install p7zip`

**Arch/Manjaro**: `sudo pacman -S p7zip`

To check whether it's been successfully installed, run `7z`. You should see an output similar to this:

```
7-Zip [64] 17.03 : Copyright (c) 1999-2020 Igor Pavlov : 2017-08-28
p7zip Version 17.03 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,4 CPUs x64)

Usage: 7z <command> [<switches>...] <archive_name> [<file_names>...]

<Commands>
  a : Add files to archive
  b : Benchmark
  d : Delete files from archive
  e : Extract files from archive (without using directory names)
  h : Calculate hash values for files
  i : Show information about supported formats
  l : List contents of archive
  rn : Rename files in archive
  t : Test integrity of archive
  u : Update files to archive
  x : eXtract files with full paths

<Switches>
  -- : Stop switches parsing
  @listfile : set path to listfile that contains file names
  -ai[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard} : Include archives
  -ax[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard} : eXclude archives
  -ao{a|s|t|u} : set Overwrite mode
  -an : disable archive_name field
  -bb[0-3] : set output log level
  -bd : disable progress indicator
  -bs{o|e|p}{0|1|2} : set output stream for output/error/progress line
  -bt : show execution time statistics
  -i[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard} : Include filenames
  -m{Parameters} : set compression Method
    -mmt[N] : set number of CPU threads
    -mx[N] : set compression level: -mx1 (fastest) ... -mx9 (ultra)
  -o{Directory} : set Output directory
  -p{Password} : set Password
  -r[-|0] : Recurse subdirectories
  -sa{a|e|s} : set Archive name mode
  -scc{UTF-8|WIN|DOS} : set charset for for console input/output
  -scs{UTF-8|UTF-16LE|UTF-16BE|WIN|DOS|{id}} : set charset for list files
  -scrc[CRC32|CRC64|SHA1|SHA256|*] : set hash function for x, e, h commands
  -sdel : delete files after compression
  -seml[.] : send archive by email
  -sfx[{name}] : Create SFX archive
  -si[{name}] : read data from stdin
  -slp : set Large Pages mode
  -slt : show technical information for l (List) command
  -snh : store hard links as links
  -snl : store symbolic links as links
  -sni : store NT security information
  -sns[-] : store NTFS alternate streams
  -so : write data to stdout
  -spd : disable wildcard matching for file names
  -spe : eliminate duplication of root folder for extract command
  -spf : use fully qualified file paths
  -ssc[-] : set sensitive case mode
  -ssw : compress shared files
  -stl : set archive timestamp from the most recently modified file
  -stm{HexMask} : set CPU thread affinity mask (hexadecimal number)
  -stx{Type} : exclude archive type
  -t{Type} : Set type of archive
  -u[-][p#][q#][r#][x#][y#][z#][!newArchiveName] : Update options
  -v{Size}[b|k|m|g] : Create volumes
  -w[{path}] : assign Work directory. Empty path means a temporary directory
  -x[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard} : eXclude filenames
  -y : assume Yes on all queries
```

Now, as you can see, you can run the following command to test if a particular archive is corrupted or not. **Replace archive_name with the filename of .tar file you want to test.**

```
7z t archive_name.tar
```

In my case, an archive, **test.tar** contains 2 files and is healthy. And following is the output I received.

```
7-Zip [64] 17.03 : Copyright (c) 1999-2020 Igor Pavlov : 2017-08-28
p7zip Version 17.03 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,4 CPUs x64)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 10240 bytes (10 KiB)

Testing archive: test.tar
--
Path = test.tar
Type = tar
Physical Size = 10240
Headers Size = 2048
Code Page = UTF-8

Everything is Ok

Files: 2
Size:       7980
Compressed: 10240
```

You can see that "**Everything is Ok**" has been outputted, which means the archive is healthy.

---

Now I've intentionally made that same archive corrupt. Let's see what `7z t test.tar` outputs now.

```
7-Zip [64] 17.03 : Copyright (c) 1999-2020 Igor Pavlov : 2017-08-28
p7zip Version 17.03 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,4 CPUs x64)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 10224 bytes (10 KiB)

Testing archive: test1.tar
ERROR: test1.tar
test1.tar
Open ERROR: Can not open the file as [tar] archive


ERRORS:
Is not archive
    
Can't open as archive: 1
Files: 0
Size:       0
Compressed: 0
```

You can see that it outputs various messages like "**Can not open the file as [tar] archive.**" and "**Is not archive**". You might get **similar or same** messages if your archive is corrupted.

Comment: so supposedly this should work if I am piping the output of another command into 7z, but it  passes even when I pipe garbage into it  ` | 7z t -si -ttar` ...